# Insertar varios datos en una celda con mysql

Tags: mysql, nodejs

Estoy desarrollando una pagina web donde visualizo contenido de Libros usando node js, mysql y ejs para renderizar las consultas de los datos de cada libro, de la siguiente forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces en esta seccion de filtrar por categorias, igualmente renderizo la informacion desde una tabla de mysql , de la siguiente forma, (solo es una tabla) :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces hasta ahi todo bien, pero tengo un apartado para mostrar las palabras claves que se van agregando por libro, el problema aqui es que quiero encontrar una forma de que si yo inserto en una celda de mysql llamada "claves" e inserto algo como "palabra1,palabra2,palabra3", se pueda insertar en una sola celda y se muestre de la siguiente forma :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi codigo para realizar la insercion de datos por cada libro, primero el codigo lee un archivo excel, obtiene cada valor de cada columna y fila y lo pasa o inserta a la base de datos en la columna correspondiente, de esta forma :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui hago varias consultas para cada apartado de los filtros y las opciones o checkbox se puedan visualizar sin que sean repetidos :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y los muestro en el ejs asi :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][9]][9]

Comment: El código va como texto (y **no** como imagen) para que podamos reproducir el error o bien para responderte sin tener que teclearlo todo de nuevo. Léete [ask], [tour] y [example] para aprender el funcionamiento básico de este sitio y que tus preguntas tengan mejor aceptación por la comunidad (y así te podrán ayudar más rápido y mejor)

Comment: Por otra parte, no se ve tu intento para juntar esas claves en una cadena separada por comas... ¿donde lo has intentado y que error te ha dado?

Comment: Quiero advertir que lo que intentas hacer, aunque parezca simple de entrada, no lo es, aparte de ser un pésimo diseño. Si en un futuro x ejemplo tú quieres saber cuántos elementos tienen la palabra clave `emociones` será harto difícil porque tendrás que empezar a buscar en una lista separada por comas en vez de buscar por un índice. Otro problema grave aquí es que tu código quedará expuesto a posibles errores ortográficos o de otra naturaleza, como que escriban en algún caso `emocione`, olviden una coma etc. Nunca fue una buena idea expresar relaciones en listas separadas por comas.

Comment: @A.Cedano No estan difícil, aunque quizás no tan optimo como lo pudieran ser los índices, usando [find_in_set](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_find_in_set.asp).  El hecho de querer usar índices creo que implica una tabla nueva (para no repetir registros) y las palabras claves de forma individual en un campo, asociandolas a los id de la tabla original (por así llamarla) con un campo de id_libros por ejemplo.

Comment: @masterguru aún así, el diseño es precario, como dije, parece fácil, porque de entrada pensar en diseñar otra tabla puede hacer creer que todo será más costoso, que se desperdiciará espacio, que qué rollo, diseñar una tabla para esta simpleza, etc y no es así. A la larga este diseño ocupará más espacio y podría saltar por los aires cuando haya un requerimiento mínimamente complejo: *búscame las `emociones` que tengan `listas` pero no `palabras` entre las fechas tal y tal*  habrá que escribir un código rocambolesco para esto tan simple y no digamos nada de la propensión a errores de escritura.

Comment: @A.Cedano Entiendo tu sugerencia, y la apoyo. Aún así, creo que se podría hacer igualmente, entiendo que de este modo: `WHERE FIND_IN_SET('emociones', claves) AND FIND_IN_SET('listas', claves)  AND NOT FIND_IN_SET('palabras', claves) AND date>blabla AND date<bleble` (donde blabla, bleble son datos de fechas según sean de un tipo u otro)... En resumen, sigue siendo posible, quizás más largo, pero posible.

Comment: @masterguru no digo que sea imposible, pero cuando digo que la App puede saltar por los aires me refiero a que una consulta como la que sugieres, en una BD más o menos grande, empezará a ser lenta con el tiempo, haciéndose insostenible. Diseñar como lo está haciendo OP en este caso va contra uno de los principios de las bases de datos: la relacionalidad. Revisa las respuestas a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6631851/5587982), allí hay enlaces interesantes aparte de las respuestas.

Comment: @A.Cedano Ok, ya veo lo que indicas, de hecho te daba la razón, simplemente dudaba en si conocias o desconocias el **find_in_set** que permitia el acceso más racional a esas series de valores separados por comas directamente en MySQL (sin tener que sacar todo el campo y luego desmenuzarlo en PHP u otro lenguaje después). Aclarado :-) Saludos!